# How can i go back to previous Activity using LayoutParams?

Tags: android, android-studio

Actually i have added a fragment on my entire activity layout with the help of LayoutParams, almost i have done this but the problem is when i want to go back to my previous activity with the help of onbackpressed button then its just push me to the empty LayoutParams layout.

```
 //Creating Custom layout for replacing fragment with activity layout
            frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
            frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            frameLayout.setId(R.id.fragmentLayout);

            setContentView(frameLayout);
            SendtoFragment(new SettingFragment());



   public void SendtoFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentLayout, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: You want go to previous activity or fragment with back press?

Comment: The `LayoutParams` doesn't really have anything to do with it. Pressing the back button is simply removing the `Fragment` from the `FrameLayout` because you've called `addToBackStack()` on the `FragmentTransaction`. If you want a back press to finish the current `Activity` instead, remove that `addToBackStack()` call.

Comment: Mike M . I have tried your suggestion but its just finish my application

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i able to replace a entire fragment on my entire activity in accurate way ?

Comment: "its just finish my application" – If you started this `Activity` from another `Activity`, do not call `finish()` in that first `Activity` if you want to go back to it. Btw, you have to put @ in front of my username for me to be notified of your comments; i.e., @MikeM.

Comment: Okay Sure thanks ! but can you please suggest me any other method to put a fragment on entire activity, it would be a great help @MikeM.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. You basically did that in the code you've shown. The only other ways to do that are just minor variations of what you did; e.g., you could put that `FrameLayout` into a layout instead, and call `setContentView()` with that `R.layout`. Or, you could put a `<fragment>` element in the layout directly, then you wouldn't have to do the `FragmentTransaction` in code, but you couldn't remove the `Fragment` later.